# Flask: Login without authentication

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I have a Flask application that I need to have a login for but I do not need authentication. The username and password fields need to be sent to an already created function that signs in the user to a netscaler. This function returns a session key. Also if multiple people are accessing the web application, how can I keep each of their sessions separate? I do not want to register any users as that is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have your login functionality and simple need to keep the session key around to differentiate between users, use the [`session`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.session) proxy:

```
session['key'] = your_login_function(request.form.get('username'), request.form.get('password'))
```

To check if the user is logged in, check that key in `session`:

```
if 'key' in session:
    # there's a logged-in user
```

[`app.before_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.before_request) is a great place for this as it's called before each request:

```
@app.before_request
def _check_user_login():
    if not request.path.startswith('/static/') and \
            not request.path in ['/urls', '/that', '/do', '/not', '/require', '/login']:
        if not 'key' in session:
            return redirect(url_for('your_login_page'))
```

To restrict how long the user can stay logged in under that key, set the session's `permanent` value to True and configure [`permanent_session_lifetime`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.permanent_session_lifetime) to be how long you want the login to be valid

```
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = # ...

session['key'] = # ...
session.permanent = True
```

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, the netscaler takes care of the authentication in the backend since it's tied to AD. I have a function that returns a session key already but the parameters for the function take in username and password which I needed to pass to it(which isn't the hard part). I just wasn't sure how I can keep a 'session' valid per user sign in so that when a second person signs on to the application trying to access it the first person's session isn't overridden nor a second person see the first's data being displayed. I will try what you've suggested now. @Celeo

Comment: @Sean Thanks for the clarification! I've updated my answer to be more relevant.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You gave a correct answer and then some! I was going to search how to restrict how long users can stay signed in, awesome answer! @Celeo